# Chef cookbook - copy file to local user with '~' ruby variable

Tags: ruby, macos, chef-infra, chef-recipe, user-environment

Well, let's start by saying I'm a chef noob and I am trying to hash this code out.

I am in a full mac shop.  I am using Chef to automate system wide changes.  As I'm new, I'm rolling it out onto our Mac AV systems.

Basically, there is a folder on a file server that has MAC SCREEN SAVERS directory.  I copy the server directory locally to the MAC OS X /User/user_name/Pictures directory.

So, this is what I got in chef:

```
    local_folder_modified = File.mtime("~/Pictures/SCREEN SAVER NEW MACS")
    server_folder_modified = File.mtime("/Volumes/SERVER/SCREEN\ SAVER\ NEW\ MACS/")


    if server_folder_modified != local_folder_modified
              # file has changed
    then
            require 'fileutils'

                    FileUtils.cd('server_folder_modified') do
                    FileUtils.rm('local_folder_modified/*')
                    FileUtils.cp_r './*', 'local_folder_modified'
            Else
                    end
    end
```

Anyways, I can't figure how to set the '~' to be the running user of this recipe.  So, if Comp_A has user Jim_Beam and Comp_B has user Jack_Daniels, I don't want to set the code to be:
      ENV[HOME] = /user/jimbeam
As it won't work on Jack_Daniels.  Right?

I've read that file.expand will work, or ENV, but I am really unsure what will be the best code to say
"hey, I want the current user that will need this screen saver - so set the environment as a variable so it works across different nodes".

Anyways, thanks for your help.  I hope I am making sense!

Comment: ::File.expand_path("~/Pictures/SCREEN SAVER NEW MACS") will expand the path for you. As a side note, I cannot see any chef dsl in the example you give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use File.expand.  It will expand the tilde `~` to be the the home directory of the user running this cookbook.  Alternatively, you could do:

```
"#{ENV['HOME']}/Pictures/SCREEN SAVER NEW MACS"
```

Like the previous comment, this is not chef DSL or ruby code.  What is the source of this code or is it just pseudo-code to ask the question?

Also, chef-client is not frequently run as multiple users in a chef server deployment.  It's usually run in a sudo context.  So maybe you are referring to a --local-mode or chef-zero application?

Comment: Awesome- thank you!  Yeah, I'm just wrapping my head around Chef now.

Comment: Oops - hit enter too quick.  

This is pretty much the code that's in a default.rb in a cookbook.  I don't know if that answers your question (sorry if it doesn't).

BTW - I did NOT know about the chef-client user thing as that is SUPER helpful!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use file stat of `/dev/console` to get the current user. Depending how you are running the chef-client `Env[‘Home’]` might not give you want you want. Try this:

```
console_user = Etc.getpwuid(::File.stat("/dev/console").uid).name
home_dir = ::File.join(‘Users’, console_user)
```

You can see that the chef [launchd provider](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/294742ef45336b97cafc1742c6adfd1d6657c710/lib/chef/provider/launchd.rb#L113) uses this method to determine the console user

Also there is a much simpler way to do what you are trying to accomplish with the remote_file resource. Try this:

```
console_user = Etc.getpwuid(::File.stat("/dev/console").uid).name
home_dir = ::File.join(‘Users’, console_user)
pics = ::File.join("#{home_dir}/Pictures/")
server_base_url = "https://PLACE_WHERE_STORE/Wallpapers")
[
  ‘Pic1’,
  ‘Pic2’,
].each do |pic|
  remote_file ::File.join(pics, pic) do
    source “#{server_base_url}/#{pic}”
    owner console_user
    group console_user
    mode '0755'
    action :create
  end
end
```

For added security you should also include checksum